# Mover para ul vazia sortable jQuery

Tags: jquery, sortable

Tenho uma página com 3 ul sortable, não consigo mover a div para ul vazia, poderiam dar uma verificado no meu código. Na imagem de exemplo não consigo mover o conteudo da div Prospect para as ul vazias Negociação e Fechamento. Quando todas as ul possuem registro consigo mover de uma para outra normalmente, o problema é quando uma fica vazia aí não consigo mover para ela novamente.

```js
// retorna oportunidade
function listaOportunidade() {

  $.ajax({
    type: 'post', //Definimos o método HTTP usado
    dataType: 'json', //Definimos o tipo de retorno
    url: 'models/readOportunidade.php', //Definindo o arquivo onde serão buscados os dados
    success: function(dados) {
      var linhaProspect = 0,
        linhaNegociacao = 0,
        linhaFechamento = 0,
        valorProspect = 0,
        valProspect = 0,
        valorNegociacao = 0,
        valNegociacao = 0,
        valorFechamento = 0,
        valFechamento = 0,
        prospect = [],
        negociacao = [],
        fechamento = [];
      $.each(dados, function(key, val) {

        var id = val.oportunidadeId;
        var valor = parseFloat(val.oportunidadeReceita);
        var moeda = valor.toLocaleString("pt-BR", {
          style: "currency",
          currency: "BRL"
        });
        var card =
          '<li class="group" id="' + id + '">' +
          '<div class="card font14">' +
          '<input type="hidden" value="' + id + '" name="idOp">' +
          '<div class="card-header blue-grey lighten-5 text-muted">' +
          '<div class="row">' +
          '<div class="col-sm-4 mb-0"><i class="fa fa-phone mr-1"></i>' + val.oportunidadeLinha + '</div>' +
          '<div class="col-sm-8 mb-0 text-right">' + moeda + '</div>' +
          '</div></div>' +
          '<div class="card-body text-center" style="height:80px;">' +
          '<input type="hidden" value="' + val.oportunidadeFunil + '" name="opFunil">' +
          '<span class="card-text">' + val.clienteNome + '</span>' +
          '<small class="bottom-align-text text-right font-weight-bold text-primary">' + val.oportunidadeTipo + '</small>' +
          '</div>' +
          '<div class="card-footer text-muted" ng-init="tooltip()">' +
          '<button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-rounded mb-0 mt-0 btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalDetalhes"><i class="fa fa-search mr-1"></i>Detalhes</button>' +
          '<button class="btn-floating btn-sm btn-danger pull-right mt-0 mb-0" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalPerdido" data-tt="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Negócio Perdido"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i></button>' +
          '<button class="btn-floating btn-sm btn-success pull-right mt-0 mb-0" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalGanho" data-tt="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Negócio Ganho"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></button>' +
          '</div></div></li>'
        if (val.oportunidadeFunil == 'PROSPECT') {
          linhaProspect += parseInt(val.oportunidadeLinha);
          valorProspect += parseFloat(val.oportunidadeReceita);
          valProspect = valorProspect.toLocaleString("pt-BR", {
            style: "currency",
            currency: "BRL"
          });
          prospect.push(card);
        } else {

        }
        if (val.oportunidadeFunil == 'NEGOCIAÇÃO') {
          linhaNegociacao += parseInt(val.oportunidadeLinha);
          valorNegociacao += parseFloat(val.oportunidadeReceita);
          valNegociacao = valorNegociacao.toLocaleString("pt-BR", {
            style: "currency",
            currency: "BRL"
          });
          negociacao.push(card);
        } else {

        }
        if (val.oportunidadeFunil == 'FECHAMENTO') {
          linhaFechamento += parseInt(val.oportunidadeLinha);
          valorFechamento += parseFloat(val.oportunidadeReceita);
          valFechamento = valorFechamento.toLocaleString("pt-BR", {
            style: "currency",
            currency: "BRL"
          });
          fechamento.push(card);
        }


        $("ul.droptrue").sortable({
          connectWith: "ul",
          scroll: false,
          revert: true,
          opacity: 0.8,
          sort: function(e, ui) {
            ui.item.toggleClass("highlight");
            $(".ui-state-highlight").css({
              "width": "100%",
              "height": ui.item.height()
            });
          },
          update: function(event, ui) {
            var opFunil = $('input[name="opFunil"]').val();
            var post = $(this).sortable('serialize');
            var idOp = ui.item.attr("id");
            $.ajax({
              url: 'models/updateFunil.php?id=' + idOp,
              type: 'post',
              data: {
                opFunil: opFunil
              },
              success: function(retorno) {
                console.log(retorno);
                listaOportunidade();
              }
            });
          }
        });
        

      });
      $('#linhaProspect').html(linhaProspect);
      $('#valorProspect').html(valProspect);
      $('#prospect').html(prospect);
      $('#linhaNegociacao').html(linhaNegociacao);
      $('#valorNegociacao').html(valNegociacao);
      $('#negociacao').html(negociacao);
      $('#linhaFechamento').html(linhaFechamento);
      $('#valorFechamento').html(valFechamento);
      $('#fechamento').html(fechamento);
    }
  });
}
listaOportunidade();
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="card border-light font-samsung-700">
      <div class="card-header font20 light-blue lighten-5 text-muted">
        <i class="fa fa-bullhorn mr-1"></i> PROSPECÇÃO
        <hr>
        <div class="d-block">
          <span class="d-block"><i class="fa fa-mobile mr-1"></i> <b id="linhaProspect" class="text-left"></b> <b id="valorProspect" class="float-right"></b></span>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <ul class="list-group droptrue connectedSortable" id="prospect">

    </ul>

  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="card border-light font-samsung-700">
      <div class="card-header font20 yellow lighten-5 brown-text">
        <i class="fa fa-bullhorn mr-1"></i> NEGOCIAÇÃO
        <hr>
        <div class="d-block">
          <span class="d-block"><i class="fa fa-mobile mr-1"></i> <b id="linhaNegociacao" class="text-left"></b> <b id="valorNegociacao" class="float-right"></b></span>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <ul class="list-group  connectedSortable" id="negociacao">

    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="card border-light font-samsung-700">
      <div class="card-header font20 green lighten-5 brown-text">
        <i class="fa fa-bullhorn mr-1"></i> FECHAMENTO
        <hr>
        <div class="d-block">
          <span class="d-block"><i class="fa fa-mobile mr-1"></i> <b id="linhaFechamento" class="text-left"></b> <b id="valorFechamento" class="float-right"></b></span>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <ul class="list-group droptrue connectedSortable" id="fechamento">

    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]